# Перевод расшифровка

Tags: json, кодировка, unicode

```
      "value": "True",
      "timestamp": 0
    },
    "\u00d0\u009a\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b4 \u00d0\u00bf\u00d0\u00b5\u00d1\u0080\u00d0\u00b2\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b9 \u00d1\u0081\u00d1\u0082\u00d1\u0080\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00bd\u00d1\u008b": {
      "href": "",
      "value": "KG",
      "timestamp": 0
    },
    "\u00d0\u009f\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b4\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00bb\u00d1\u0081\u00d1\u008f(-\u00d0\u00b0\u00d1\u0081\u00d1\u008c) \u00d0\u00bf\u00d1\u0080\u00d1\u008f\u00d0\u00bc\u00d1\u008b\u00d0\u00bc \u00d1\u008d\u00d1\u0084\u00d0\u00b8\u00d1\u0080\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00bc": {
      "href": "",
      "value": "True",
      "timestamp": 0
    },
    "\u00d0\u009f\u00d0\u00be\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b4\u00d0\u00bd\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00b9 \u00d0\u00b2\u00d1\u0085\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b4": {
      "href": "",
      "value": "",
      "timestamp": 1697725084
    },
    "\u00d0\u009f\u00d0\u00be\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b4\u00d0\u00bd\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00b9 \u00d0\u00b2\u00d1\u008b\u00d1\u0085\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b4": {
      "href": "",
      "value": "",
      "timestamp": 1695239320
    },
    "\u00d0\u0094\u00d0\u00b0\u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00b0 \u00d0\u00b8 \u00d0\u00b2\u00d1\u0080\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bc\u00d1\u008f \u00d1\u0080\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00b7\u00d0\u00bc\u00d0\u00b5\u00d1\u0089\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bd\u00d0\u00b8\u00d1\u008f \u00d0\u00bf\u00d0\u00b5\u00d1\u0080\u00d0\u00b2\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b9 \u00d0\u00b8\u00d1\u0081\u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00be\u00d1\u0080\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00b8": {
      "href": "",
      "value": "",
      "timestamp": 1549973930
    },
    "\u00d0\u0092\u00d1\u0080\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bc\u00d1\u008f \u00d0\u00bf\u00d0\u00be\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b4\u00d0\u00bd\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b9 \u00d0\u00b8\u00d1\u0081\u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00be\u00d1\u0080\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00b8": {
      "href": "",
      "value": "",
      "timestamp": 1704154649
    },
    "\u00d0\u0092\u00d1\u0080\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bc\u00d1\u008f \u00d0\u00bf\u00d0\u00b5\u00d1\u0080\u00d0\u00b2\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b9 \u00d0\u00b8\u00d1\u0081\u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00be\u00d1\u0080\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00b8 \u00d0\u00b4\u00d0\u00bb\u00d1\u008f \u00d0\u00b1\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00b7\u00d0\u00ba\u00d0\u00b8\u00d1\u0085 \u00d0\u00b4\u00d1\u0080\u00d1\u0083\u00d0\u00b7\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b9": {
      "href": "",
      "value": "",
      "timestamp": 0
    }
  }
}
```

]
}

Comment: Выглядит как будто кто-то CP1251 затолкал в JSON.

Comment: Вопрос никак не относится к wpf. Поставьте релевантные метки!

Comment: Здравствуйте Александр вы что то понимаете в этом можно ваш номер телефона мне очень нужна помощь если можно конечно

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov вопрос? Где этот вопрос?

Comment: Можно пожалуйста расшифровать что там написано

Comment: @СабинаСагыманова сайт не занимается такими вопросами. Я чисто ради интереса кидал их в GPT и [вот что](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIxnj.png) он мне выдал.

Comment: Это что за блогершу вы взламываете?)))

Comment: Нет не блогерша там должна было быть переписка.participants": [
    {
      "name": "_aelita777_"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ulan Turanov"
    }
  ],
  "messages": [
    {
      "sender_name": "_aelita777_",
      "timestamp_ms": 1702547061049,
      "content": "\u00f0\u009f\u0098\u0082\u00f0\u009f\u0098\u0082\u00f0\u009f\u0098\u0082",
      " а тут что написано можете сказать

Comment: Можно ваш ватсап пожалуйста  )))))

Comment: "is_geoblocked_for_viewer": false
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "_aelita777_",
      "timestamp_ms": 1694537271411,
      "content": "\u00d0\u009d\u00d0\u00be \u00d0\u00b8 \u00d0\u00bd\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00b2\u00d1\u008f\u00d0\u00b7\u00d1\u008b\u00d0\u00b2\u00d0\u00b0\u00d1\u0082\u00d1\u008c\u00d1\u0081\u00d1\u008f \u00d0\u00bd\u00d0\u00b5 \u00d0\u00b1\u00d1\u0083\u00d0\u00b4\u00d1\u0083",
      "is_geoblocked_for_viewer": false
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "_aelita777_",
      "

Comment: @СабинаСагыманова WhatsApp нету, да и что связанное с номером не дам. [Тут](https://t.me/eccs0103) пишите. И удалите это. Это не вопрос, не для сайта.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
   "Код первой страны": {
      "href": "",
      "value": "KG",
      "timestamp": 0
   },
   "Поделился(-ась) прямым эфиром": {
      "href": "",
      "value": "True",
      "timestamp": 0
   },
   "Последний вход": {
      "href": "",
      "value": "",
      "timestamp": 1697725084
   },
   "Последний выход": {
      "href": "",
      "value": "",
      "timestamp": 1695239320
   },
   "Дата и время размещения первой истории": {
      "href": "",
      "value": "",
      "timestamp": 1549973930
   },
   "Время последней истории": {
      "href": "",
      "value": "",
      "timestamp": 1704154649
   },
   "Время первой истории для близких друзей": {
      "href": "",
      "value": "",
      "timestamp": 0
   }
}
```